# Java: When passing a 2d array of custom class into a constructor I lose values in the array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, constructor, libgdx

I know the title doesn't really make sense but I couldn't think how to word better, please bear with me.

I am using java with LibGDX and am trying to load data from a saved pixmap to render a map on the screen. In the pixmap, each pixel represents a hexagon's colour (the map is a grid of hexagons).

The problem is: I am loading data (specifically colours) from a pixmap to an array of a class I have called HexInfo. However when I pass this array to another class in order to draw it on my screen, every HexInfo item in the array has its colour as black. The following is how everything is set up

```
hexInfo = new HexInfo[cols][rows];

for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                {
                    Color.rgba8888ToColor(color, savedScreenData.getPixel(i, j));

                    hexInfo[i][j] = new HexInfo(i,j);
                    hexInfo[i][j].setColour(color);
                    hexInfo[i][j].setIsVisible(true);
                    hexInfo[i][j].setIsOccupied(true);

                    //It is definitely set because this gives the correct colours
                    System.out.println(hexInfo[i][j].getColour());
                }
            }
mapScreen = new MapScreen(hexInfo);
```

Here ^, the getColour printed on the screen is correct.

Then, in the MapScreen class I use a for loop to getColour for each hexInfo:

```
public MapScreen(HexInfo[][] hexInfo)
{
cols = hexInfo.length;
    rows = hexInfo[0].length;

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            if (hexInfo[i][j].isOccupied())
            System.out.println(hexInfo[i][j].getColour());
        }
    }
}
```

However, here each colour is black.

The HexInfo class is as follows:

```
public class HexInfo {

private Color colour;
private String owner;
private boolean isOccupied;
private boolean isVisible;

public Color getColour() {
    return colour;
}

public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public boolean isOccupied() {
    return isOccupied;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return isVisible;
}

public void setIsOccupied(boolean isOccupied) {
    this.isOccupied = isOccupied;
}

public void setColour(Color colour)
{
    this.colour = colour;
    System.out.println("SETTING COLOR IN HEXINFO AS: " + colour); //This also gives correct colour in sysout
}

public void updateOwner(Color color, String owner)
{

    System.out.println("setting colour in hexinfo as " + color);

    this.colour = color;
    this.owner = owner;

    isOccupied = true;
}

public void setIsVisible(boolean isVisible) {
    this.isVisible = isVisible;
}

public HexInfo(int x, int y)
{
    mapCoords = new Vector2(x,y);
    colour = new Color(Color.BLACK);
    isOccupied = false;
}
}
```

I have checked over things and don't see where the problem is. If it is with the rest of my code, let me know what other information you need (there is a lot so I obviously didn't include all of it).

Comment: You don't seem to have set `isOccupied`, which is the condition for your second check and will return `false` by default. Does your `println` statement in `MapScreen` even execute?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it does execute. I set isOccupied initially as `HexInfo[i][j].setIsOccupied(true)`. I'll just edit that in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with passing the array to a constructor.

`HexInfo` does not make a copy of the `color` when you call `setColour(...)`, it just sets a reference. Therefore, all members of your array will eventually point to the same `color` instance, and so they will all have the color of your last pixel.

Changing the inner-most part of your nested for-loops like so should fix it:

```
hexInfo[i][j] = new HexInfo(i,j);
hexInfo[i][j].setIsVisible(true);
hexInfo[i][j].setIsOccupied(true);

Color.rgba8888ToColor(hexInfo[i][j].getColour(), savedScreenData.getPixel(i, j));

//It is now *really* definitely set because this gives the correct colours
System.out.println(hexInfo[i][j].getColour());
```

Comment: He's using an array of HexInfos.

Comment: @tgm1024 I know. But s/he calls the `setColour(...)` method of each member of the array with the same `color` object.

Comment: Good spotting. Plus 1.

Comment: @thomas, gotcha.  Good job.  I missed that way he's creating the color in the first place.  +1'd your answer and comment

Comment: Based on original answer, I changed the setColour to this: `this.color = new Color(colour)`. Is there anything wrong with this, because it does work?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, you only create some "unnecessary" Color objects that way: once in the constructor of `HexInfo` (which basically just gets thrown away) and once in `setColor`. In any event, you should make clear (e.g. in documentation) which behavior `setColor` implements, especially if `setColor` is supposed to be used in other parts of your code as well. If you want the copying behavior every time, changing `setColour` you just did probably makes sense, but it could also make sense to leave it the way it was. Your pick.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help and explanation. Should I change title or something so that if people are searching for this problem they can find this question? If so, what should I change it to?

Comment: Don't know either :-)